# How do I convert a dashmap to hashmap

Tags: rust, hashmap, rust-tokio

I recently decided to use `dashmap` since `tokio` recommends it
instead of implementing sharding myself.

In some cases, where I only need readable access to it, I would like to convert the dashmap to hashmap so I can do minimal changes in those methods.
More specifically, I also wanted to serialize it, and the `ReadOnlyView` of dashmap doesn't implement the `Serialize` trait either.

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it directly via the dashmap crate.

So how do I convert a `DashMap`to a `HashMap` ?

Comment: Convert it to an iterator then create a hashmap from that?

Comment: @Masklinn ..guess i could go with that. it does have `iter` albeit with a scary note about locking behaviour under it.

Comment: I haven't used `DashMap` but it seems that most of the API surface has the same deadlock warning so I guess it is just something you need to be aware of when using this library.  The consuming [IntoIterator](https://docs.rs/dashmap/latest/dashmap/struct.DashMap.html#impl-IntoIterator) impl has no such warning

Comment: If you have ownership or `&mut` access to the dashmap, you can drain it using `dm.into_iter().collect::<HashMap<_>>()`. (If you have `&mut DashMap`, then use with `std::mem::take(dm).into_iter()...`.) Note that that will build a new HashMap and empty the dashmap, so it's an O(n) operation.